# Get total invoices per customer

Tags: mapreduce, couchdb, couchdb-2.0, fauxton

I have a database where I have docs like customers (customerId, firstName, lastName, phoneNo, eMail) and invoice (invoiceId, invoiceDate, customerId).

I want to get the sum of invoices per customer in a view. 
I'm currently using Fauxton 2.0.

My view is currently:

```
function (doc) {
    if (doc.customerId && doc.invoiceId) {
        emit(doc.customerId, doc.invoiceId);
    }
}
```

But I want to add some sort of reduce function which can give me the total sum of invoices.

thanks.

Comment: Where is your attempt? What problems are you having?

Comment: Well my map is function (doc) {  emit(doc._id, {customerId: doc.customerId, invoiceId: doc.invoiceId} ) } - and then I type into my browser http://localhost:5984/assignment/_design/view5320/_view/sumofinv?key="the id of the first customer" - and then I'm not getting any rows at all. I have also added the _sum in my mapreduce function.

Comment: Well, I solved the problem, it was just an issue of changing the reduce function _sum to _count, to get the total amount of invoices. So when requesting the key(customerId), I get the count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I solved the problem, it was just an issue of changing the reduce function _sum to _count, to get the total amount of invoices. So when requesting the key(customerId), I get the count.